# Why incorrectly recorded a negative value? NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
    mov al, -10
    mov [_resS], al
```

Output: resS = 246. Why is that? After all, "-10" value should be placed in the al register.

With the register eax is working correctly.

```
mov eax, -10
mov [_resS], eax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by *"Output"*. I.e. are you printing the value (and if so, how?), or are you looking at it in a debugger, etc?

In any case, the 8-bit values 246 and -10 share the same bit pattern in two's complement (which is what most processors use): `11110110`. Whether those bits should represent 246 or -10 depends on whether you choose to view them as a signed or an unsigned value.

However, it seems likely that your problems come from only modifying parts of the variable `_resS`.
If we assume that you print/inspect `_resS` as a 32-bit value, and that `_resS` initially contains the value 0 then it's easy to see why you get the results you describe:

1. `_resS` contains 0x00000000
2. `mov al,-10` -> `al` contains -10 (or 246), which equals 0xF6
3. `mov [_resS], al` -> `_resS` contains 0x000000F6, i.e. 246

In the second case you get this:

1. `_resS` contains 0x00000000
2. `mov eax,-10` -> `eax` contains -10, which equals 0xFFFFFFF6
3. `mov [_resS], eax` -> `resS` contains 0xFFFFFFF6, i.e. -10.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but at the time of the recording is not recorded in _resS 0, it's empty. "Output:" This conclusion _resS values in the program in C ++

Comment: A memory location can't be "empty". It has some value. When you tested this it probably had the value 0 initially. Depending on how and where you declared `_resS` that would either be the expected outcome or just a coincidence.

Comment: The variable declared in c ++ file as follows: int resS;

Comment: Uh-huh. Well, a global `int` will be intialized to zero if you don't explictly initialize it to some other value. A local non-static `int` will have an undefined initial value (i.e. its intial value could be anything, including zero).

Comment: The fix would be to use the second piece of code, i.e. write to the full 32 bits of the variable instead of just writing to its least significant byte. If you don't intend to use the value of the register afterwards you can just write directly to memory: `mov dword [_resS], -10`

Comment: yes you are right dresS, really is 0. Unfortunately I need to use only 8bit registers. Is there no other way to get around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104877/discussion-between-strelok2014strelok-and-michael).